# input tag data not uploading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I'm attempting to build an app that uploads all data from a harddrive into an array. It's just a folder with other folders in it, my idea is to upload the names of all the folders into the array. The following is my code for doing so, the problem is I'm getting "C:\fakepath\title_t00.mkv" as the value of the input when I console log it. I understand this is a security feature that prevents JavaScript from knowing your file's local full path but I obviously can't finish the project without getting all of the data.

Is there any way to do this?

```
import './App.css'; 
import {useRef, useState, useEffect} from 'react'

function App() {
  const data = useRef(null)
  const [library, setLibrary] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(data.current)
    setLibrary([data.current])
  }, [data])

  return (
    <form>
      <label>
        <div className='btn-three' >
          Select Directory:
          <input type="file" ref={data} webkitdirectory="true" onInput={(e) => {console.log(e.target.value)}}/>
        </div>
      </label>


    </form>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

So on upload, the `${inputHTMLElement}.files` will be populated with information on your files. <strike>Then you need a FileReader to access its content.</strike> (I misread the question at first and thought the goal was to get file content)

File input let you upload files within a directory. So `${inputHTMLElement}.files` will only return the list of files that are in your uploaded directory (and in nested directory as well). However for each file, there is a property `webkitRelativePath`. With that you could deduce the directory tree for all directories that contain a file. Directories that are empty will be ignored (so if a directory contains only empty directories, it will be ignored as well)

```
function App() {
  const data = useRef(null);
  const [library, setLibrary] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(data.current);
    setLibrary([data.current]);
  }, [data]);

  const getDirectories = () => {
    const directories = new Set();
    var files = data.current?.files;
    if (files) {
       for (let f of files) {
            // remove file name from the directory path and add it to the directory set
            directories.add(f.webkitRelativePath.substring(0, f.webkitRelativePath.lastIndexOf('/')));
        }
    }
    return Array.from(directories)
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <label>
        <div className="btn-three">
          Select Directory:
          <input
            type="file"
            ref={data}
            webkitdirectory="true"
            onChange={() => {
              try {
                const directoryPaths = getDirectories();
                console.log(directoryPaths);
                /* do your things with the directoryPaths */
              } catch(e) {
                // handle exception
              }
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </label>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Nothing's being printed in the console when I run that code which means that data is never updated.

Comment: I had a typo (duplicated files[0].files[0]) also did you try to use onChange instead of onInput? You could also add a console.log in the handleError

Comment: Yeah I've tried onChange as well, still nothing being printed to the console with both changes (onChange and removing the duplicate)

Comment: ok actually I misread the question. I updated the solution to return all unique paths to the files contained in the directory (possibly with nested directories). This could help you determine the directory tree where leave directories contain a file. But folders that don't contain any file or nested files will be ignored.